# Python Dataframe to Columnar format for accessing the columns dynamically

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-loc

Dataframe data will be :

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 101 | 201 | 301 |
| 102 | 202 | 302 |
| 103 | 203 | 303 |

Expected output: Format as HBase (Columnar fashion)

Consider COL1 as KEY_COLUMN vaue

| KEY_COLUMN | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | COL2 | 200 |
| 100 | COL3 | 300 |
| 101 | COL2 | 201 |
| 101 | COL3 | 301 |
| 102 | COL2 | 202 |
| 102 | COL3 | 302 |
| 103 | COL2 | 203 |
| 103 | COL3 | 303 |

I tried using .loc which transpose/convert all key to value like below.

```py
for idx in df.index:
     print (df.loc[idx])
```

```
COL1  100
COL2  200
COL3  300
COL1  101
COL2  201
COL3  301
COL1  102
COL2  202
COL3  302
COL1  103
COL2  203
COL3  303
```

But I couldn't bring the KEY_COLUMN as column 1 and KEY and VALUE as subsequent columns. Could anyone please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt):

```py
df = (
    df.rename(columns={"COL1": "KEY_COLUMN"})
    .melt("KEY_COLUMN", var_name="KEY", value_name="VALUE")
    .sort_values(by="KEY_COLUMN")
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   KEY_COLUMN   KEY  VALUE
0         100  COL2    200
4         100  COL3    300
1         101  COL2    201
5         101  COL3    301
2         102  COL2    202
6         102  COL3    302
3         103  COL2    203
7         103  COL3    303
```

Comment: The above one really works... Also it deals with the columns dynamically... Shall we bring more than 1 column into Key_column ?? The above data frame has COL1 as KEY_COLUMN,  how to bring two KEY_COLUMNS as COL1 & COL2 ?